# convert Google Sheets data into specific nested JSON schema with pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following table in a sheet:

```
Title   Description Type    Param#1 Param#2 Param#3 Param#4
item1   blabla      foo     x           
item2   blabla      foo     y           
item3   blabla      bar             123     xyz     b1
item4   blabla      bar             456     sdf     a4
```

cells without value are empty. I want the following output:

```
[{
      "name":"item1",
      "type":"foo",
      "params":{ 
         "Param#1":"x"
     }
   },
   { 
      "name":"item2",
      "type":"foo",
      "params":{ 
         "Param#1":"y",
      }
   },
   { 
      "name":"item3",
      "type":"bar",
      "params":{ 
         "Param#2":"123",
         "Param#3":"xyz",
         "Param#4":"b1"
      }
   },
   { 
      "name":"item4",
      "type":"bar",
      "params":{ 
         "Param#2":"456",
         "Param#3":"sdf",
         "Param#4":"a4"
}}]
```

Right now I'm running my python in Jupyter notebook. I'm reading the spreadsheet easily but after that I'm stuck:

```
sheet = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='xxxxx',
                                range='sheet!A1:G').execute()
data = sheet.get('values')
headers = data.pop(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
```

How should I proceed?

## update

using `df.to_dict(orient='records')` I'm getting really close to what I want. However I still need to find out to construct the nested object.

Comment: I believe pandas has a `to_json` method but don't think that will result in the output you desire. If it does not you would have to iterate through the DataFrame row by row building the json scema that way. To iterate over a DataFrame I suggest `df.itertuples` as it is much faster than `df.iterrows` the difference has been discussed extensively on here.